# Ubuntu-19.10 Qt Lib Anaconda-Navigator Error

Tags: qt, ubuntu, anaconda

Somewhat of a Ubuntu noob coming from windows, so i hope its an easy fix.

This is the error I get when I try to launch Anaconda:

Cannot mix incompatible Qt library (version 0x50905) with this library (version 0x50907)
Aborted (core dumped)

So my thought is that there is an environment variable that needs to be tweaked to point to a native version of qt that comes with conda. Any help would be great, i need line by line instructions if possible, still new.

Thanks

Comment: What version of Anaconda are you running? Try running `conda info` to get this information.

Answer (score 0):

I was running a retro theme on my terminal that somehow interfered with the QT versions.